# Math Libraries for Objective - C to be used in Iphone projects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math

Not wanting to re-invent the wheel, are there any open-source (or included) math libraries in Objective-C (for iPhone) that can calculate Internal Rate of Return (IRR) or Modified Internal Rate of Return (MIRR)?

I'd hate to have to re-do all that work if someone out there has already done it.

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that you can call any C or C++ library from your Objective-C code. For that matter, if you have C or C++ code that calculates the functions you want, you can drop it directly into your Objective-C code.

Answer (score 1):

GNU is another option for any kind of mathematical calculation but it is a C library so not object oriented.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Answer (score 0):

I kind of doubt that there is. Objective c just seems too theoretical and idealistic for something as dirty and practical as accounting.

You might rephrase your title (and question) to indicate that you are looking for a Financial/Accounting Library and not just a general math library. I know you mention IRR and MIRR, but if someone sees "Math Libraries" in the title, they will be thinking of a totally different kind of math. Hopefully someone who knows accounting will glance at your title and know the answer!

Edit:

This probably isn't quite what you're looking for, but QuantLib is ported to many different languages. Objective-C doesn't appear to be among them.

http://quantlib.org/index.shtml

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962057/are-there-any-bsd-or-lgpl-libraries-for-calculating-amortization-schedules

Comment: quantlib works for c++, which is easily enough embedded within Objective-C (becoming Objective-C++) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-c#Objective-C.2B.2B

Comment: Thanks! Not nearly qualified enough in Objective-C to know that!

Comment: also see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1

Comment: Made it a community wiki if you'd like to add that in the body of the response.

Comment: -1 ."Too theoretical and idealistic"? What does this even mean?

Comment: An fascinating video of quant lib on iPhone: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ck3SMXybFZ8