# How to solve mathematic equation in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, equation

Simple one: 2 + x = 8

Complex one: 3 + 26 * (8 + cos(x)) = 200

Can anyone give some sample to solve above equations to work out the x in Objective C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Math Libraries for Objective - C to be used in Iphone projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045528/math-libraries-for-objective-c-to-be-used-in-iphone-projects)

Comment: Are you trying to write code to solve a single, specific expression?  Or are you wanting the code to parse an arbitrary equation and generate an answer?

Comment: Can anyone give some sample to solve above equations to work out the x in Objective C?

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C's verbosity (usually a great asset, IMHO) can make for very cumbersome mathematical expressions.

C++ is popular for maths, as it has operator over-loading, which helps to provide good readability.

The equations that you referenced above could easily be expressed in Objective-C (*with the constraint that you'll have to make x the subject of the equation yourself*), however if you're looking to do more complex work, perhaps fall back to plain-C and use: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/